# Sticky elements with background-attachment as fixed

Tags: html, css

Consider this: http://jsfiddle.net/yP7Nf

Sample code:

```
<div class="first"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>

.first {
background-color: #a6a6a6;
height: 600px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x500");
}

.second {
background-color: #fff;
min-height: 500px;


}

.third {
background-color: #ff0000;
min-height: 500px;
background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

I want the cat picture to stay sticky so the second div ('.second') can cover it the same way it covers the background.

I want to simulate the same behaviour as background-attachment:fixed with the cat picture.

Help.

Comment: are you just looking for something as simple as this: `img{position:fixed;}`

Comment: tried it, but the cat goes over the second div, not under

Comment: not sure if this is what you are after http://jsfiddle.net/yP7Nf/19/

Answer (score 0):

on your image, use a `position : fixed` to prevent it from the scroll, and a `z-index:-1` to make it go behind the things

if it goes behind something you don't want, use z-index:-2 on it